# How can I create channel just below a specific channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating auto voice channels feature for my bot but whenever a user connects to create a new VC, bot creates it in bottom of the category but I want my bot to create VC just below the channel they connected in.
For Ex. If someone connect to VC Named "Create Duo" then his VC Should be created just next to Create DUO Channel.
Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
        if after.channel.id == 875615200433274950:
            for guild in client.guilds:
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(
                    guild.categories, id=875614706612707360)
                channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"{member.display_name}'s Duo VC", category=maincategory, user_limit= 2)
                await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, manage_channels=True)
                await member.move_to(channel2)

                def check(x, y, z):
                    return len(channel2.members) == 0
                await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
                await channel2.delete()


        elif after.channel.id == 875616237508522074:
            for guild in client.guilds:
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(
                    guild.categories, id=875614706612707360)
                channel3 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"{member.display_name}'s Trio VC", category=maincategory, user_limit= 3)
                await channel3.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, manage_channels=True)
                await member.move_to(channel3)

                def check(x, y, z):
                    return len(channel3.members) == 0
                await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
                await channel3.delete()

        elif after.channel.id == 875616352260489216:
            for guild in client.guilds:
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(
                    guild.categories, id=875614706612707360)
                channel4 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"{member.display_name}'s Squad VC", category=maincategory, user_limit= 4)
                await channel4.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, manage_channels=True)
                await member.move_to(channel4)
```

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify, discord with channel works this way at the top you have the text channels and at the bottom, you have voice channels you can't put a voice channel above a text channel
after that, you can change the position of a voice_channel with edit, or when you create it you can add a kwarg of position = number if you want it at the top you can do position = 0 you can read more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#voicechannel)
and example at one of your channelss:

```py
channel4 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"{member.display_name}'s Squad VC", category=maincategory, user_limit= 4,position=0)
```